# what is the differences between MKS Integrity and Github as code versioning

Tags: git, mks-integrity

My team has been using MKS Integrity as source versioning of code. We are interested in migrated to Github and modernize our system.

What are the advantages/disadvantages between Github and MKS Integrity?

Answer (score 7):

I'm no MKS expert, but I used it a couple of years ago. It might be a different configuration from what you are using, but here are some points from my experience.

- Git is much, much faster
- Easier to work on the same files (no more unlocking and locking files).
- Branching and merging was a real pain in MKS for me, in git it's easier
- Decentralized repository meaning every developer has a copy of the code locally and don't have to be connected to to the MKS Source server to work.
- Tooling - Many IDE's have support for git and github. I tried MKS-plugin once with IntelliJ, but it IntelliJ wouldn't even start after that. I see you mention github, and they have a [desktop tool for Windows and Mac](https://desktop.github.com/)
- The community - if you are stuck it's easy to get help with git
- Since gits way of tracking changes, not versioning the whole file like MKS, it uses less disk.
- What you might be missing is MKS Manager, the issue tracking utility, where you have change packages that link file changes to a issue. Git don't have that built in. We usually solve it by referencing the task in the commit message.

  ```
  TASK-001 Fixed the thing
  ```
- Git is different in many aspects, so moving from MKS to git, can be a steep learning curve if you've never touched it before. But as a former MKS user I would never ever in a million years go back to MKS after I've started using git. I find git more flexible and you can pretty much define the process for your team, but with MKS I was stuck with that clunky MKS Client, and almost forces you to work in a single branch. Also tracking down co-workers who had locked that file I needed to check in... oh wait, he's on vacation. Better call an MKS admin who can unlock that file for me :)